# Creating ethereum accounts and getting private keys on the same time in web3js

Tags: web3js

I want to create an account using web3js and I need to the accounts private key in the same script. Are there any npm packages or web3 commands that would let me do that?

An example of what I would want to do:

```
privateKey = web3.CreateAccount();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with web3 1.0 like this

```
account = web3.eth.accounts.create([entropy]);
```

`account` is an object with the following structure:

`address` - string: The account address.

`privateKey` - string: The accounts private key. This should never be shared or stored

The object also gives you functions to sign transactions. For more details see the related [web3 documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#create)